# Connecting a synthesizer (Prophet Rev 2) directly to speakers/monitors

Tags: synthesizer, cable, monitors, studio-monitors

I intend to buy a Prophet Rev 2 synth very soon, but before I do, I want to make sure the setup I have in mind will work.

This synth has 4 quarter inch (unbalanced) audio outputs, as illustrated on page 13 of the [Manual](https://www.davesmithinstruments.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Prophet-Rev2-Users-Guide-1.0.pdf?x72411). I was thinking of buying a pair of studio monitors to hear myself playing. While shopping, I noticed that a lot of these monitors don't seem to have the same ports. For instance, those [Presonus Eris](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075QVMBT9) have two "balanced TRS" ports and two "unbalanced RCA" ports.

I really don't know much about speakers. **The question is: in a situation like this, is it possible to use these monitors with this synth and if so, what kinds of cables should I be using (TS, TSR, something else?).**

Here is some additional information, if that helps answering:

- I do not plan on using another instrument, so I'd like to avoid buying a mixer for now
- I do not plan on recording for now, so I'd like to avoid buying any interface
- I use headphones at work a lot, so I'd like not to use them in my hobby

This is my first post in this StackExchange. I apologize in advance if this is too off-topic and thank you all for your time and patience

Comment: To use speakers, you'll need to get an amplifier. This synth is not designed to drive speakers directly.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Would active monitors work (ones that have built-in amplifiers) or is an amp absolutely necessary?

Comment: Active monitors with a preamp volume control perhaps, but they're still designed for line level not instrument.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, I am still confused. I was under the impression that synthesizer outputs were line level (even though they are "instruments"), and you are saying that active monitors are designed for line level. So that should work well together, no?

Comment: It probably depends on your definition of [line level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) or see https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/understanding-signal-levels-audio-gear/ As I don't know the o/p levels of your synth nor the i/p levels of your as yet theoretical monitors, I can't make any assumptions beyond that.

Comment: Most (all) synthesizers have a line output. When a sound interface proposes a Line-in/instrument switch, the instrument mode (also called Hi-Z) is designed for electric guitar or bass.

Answer (score 1):

Prophet outputs are unbalanced. Then a pair of jack TS - RCA could be what you are looking for. I assume you have the Eris active speakers you have described.